# using a while loop to count and display numbers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

The question I am stuck on requires having the user input a "base 5 number"
(a number containing only 0s, 1s, 2s, 3s, or/and 4s)

I must test the number to see whether it is in fact a base 5 number, if so, I have to output the number of occurences of each number (number of 0s, number of 1s, etc.)

I have looked online already for advice but most of what I've found uses things that haven't been covered in the course material, and it's very important to me that I understand and grasp the course-related material.

For example, I know most people would use "arrays" for this, but I can't do that in this case.

So to clarify exactly what I am looking for then, is to be able to perform what is needed in this question, using WHILE loop.

Here's one of my attempts:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int zeros = 0;
    int ones = 0;
    int twos = 0;
    int threes = 0;
    int fours = 0;

    int number;


    cout << "Please enter a base 5 number\n";
    cin >> number;
    cout << endl;

    while (cin.get() == '0')
    {
        zeros++;
    }

    while (cin.get() == '1')
    {
        ones++;
    }

    while (cin.get() == '2')
    {
        twos++;
    }

    while (cin.get() == '3')
    {
        threes++;
    }

    while (cin.get() == '4')
    {
        fours++;
    }

    cout << "Number of Zeros: " << zeros;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Ones: " << ones;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Twos: " << twos;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Threes: " << threes;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Fours: " << fours;
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I've tried with and without the single quotations around the numbers, and many other minor variations of the code to no avail.
Also I believe I'm missing an "if" statement to test if it is in fact a base 5 number before using the "whiles" but I just can't think of a way to test that

Perhaps something like:

```
while (cin.get() != '0' || '1' || '2' || '3' || '4')
```

......

?

and either way, the "whiles" aren't even counting in this case and I can't figure out why!

Also, the reason why I chose to try this method (aside from requiring the use of a while loop and the other associated course-related topics), I used the same method in a previous program that worked perfectly. The previous one was essentially a user inputting a string and I had to count and output the number of characters within it (including spaces, symbols, etc.) until the user hits "return".  Here's part of that old code:

```
char input;
int counter = 0;

while (cin.get() != '\n')
    {
        counter++;        
    }
```

tl;dr input base 5 number, count+output number of occurences of each number, must use while loop

Comment: You haven't actually explained what problem you're facing, as far as I can tell. I don't understand these `cin.get()` loops. Are you trying to parse `number`?

Comment: your program only allows inputs where the digits are in increasing order… e. g. `013` or `1234`.

Answer (score 0):

You are accepting the input as an `int`, then checking against `char`. If you really want to check against each `char`, you should accept a `string` then use a `for` loop to iterate over each letter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int zeros = 0;
    int ones = 0;
    int twos = 0;
    int threes = 0;
    int fours = 0;

    string number;


    cout << "Please enter a base 5 number\n";
    cin >> number;
    cout << endl;

    for (char digit : number)
    {
        if (digit == '0')
        {
            zeros++;
        }
        else if (digit == '1')
        {
            ones++;
        }
        else if (digit == '2')
        {
            twos++;
        }
        else if (digit == '3')
        {
            threes++;
        }
        else if (digit == '4')
        {
            fours++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of Zeros: " << zeros;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Ones: " << ones;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Twos: " << twos;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Threes: " << threes;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Fours: " << fours;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/9lpi)

Also instead of keeping a bunch of variables as counters, you could just use an array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int counts[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};   
    string number;   

    cout << "Please enter a base 5 number\n";
    cin >> number;
    cout << endl;

    for (char digit : number)
    {
        if (digit == '0')
        {
            counts[0]++;
        }
        else if (digit == '1')
        {
            counts[1]++;
        }
        else if (digit == '2')
        {
            counts[2]++;
        }
        else if (digit == '3')
        {
            counts[3]++;
        }
        else if (digit == '4')
        {
            counts[4]++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of Zeros: " << counts[0];
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Ones: " << counts[1];
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Twos: " << counts[2];
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Threes: " << counts[3];
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of Fours: " << counts[4];
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe the for loop and string variable is just what I was looking for, this response has given me much to think about. I can't use arrays in this case as I stated earlier because it just is now a part of the appropriate material yet. My only last worry if this works is how to test if it is in fact a base 5 number before beginning the for loop? Would I use a boolean type variable perhaps?